# Angularjs get single item

Tags: angularjs, file, uploader

in my code ng-repeat works like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
     <div ng-thumb="{ file: item._file, height: 100 }"></div>
 </li>
```

But I only need to use it one time, for example I want a thumb of the second item in a queue.
I expected that this should work in this way:

```
<div ng-thumb="{ file: uploader.queue[1]._file, height: 100 }"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above, maybe it needs to be this?

```
<div ng-thumb="{ file: uploader.queue[1]._file, height: 100 }"></div>
```

Comment: No, I forgot to write in example that extension ._file, but it wont work this way either.